# Check servers reachable or not. Need to execute loop for 15 mins

Tags: powershell, csv

Need some idea for this.

I have a scenario where i need to check server is reachable or not and if reachable then update value in excel as reachable=Y else default reachable=N. for which i am creating job and checking the state

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName $sHost -Count 1 -AsJob
Get-Job $JobID | Select State
```

it is working fine in a foreach loop.
now i need to keep this foreach loop inside some other loop and check maximum for 15 mins.
After 15 mins, which ever server having reachable=N, i have to ignore them and perform further action on the servers having reachable=Y

Need some idea on this how to build for this logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop which ends after 15 minutes could look like this:

```
$startTime = Get-Date
while($startTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)){

    # Your Test-Connection loop
}

# Move on with your script...
```

To make your `Test-Connection` work with the while loop above, you cannot use the `-AsJob` parameter. Otherwise, there will be a massive amount of Jobs.

**Edit based on comments**

Change:

```
$RebootTime = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss"
```

at the top of your script to:

```
$startTime = Get-Date
$RebootTime = $startTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Was just about to post the opposite approach `$StopTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(15)` and `While ((Get-Date) -lt $StopTime){...}` (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. one thing. before this i am rebooting the servers and while doing that i am capturing the last servers reboot time(e.g. 14-11-2018_08:22:08).need to calculate the startTime from that time to next 15 mins.. how to achieve that..??

Comment: How do you capture the servers startup time? Do you have already a DateTime object of it?

Comment: Doing like this `$RebootTime = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: Are you doing this in the same script? If yes, just use put `$startTime = Get-Date` as the next row after `$RebootTime = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: Yes.doing in the same script and also writing it in a text file. didn't understood your suggestion. how will i get the difference is 15 mins or so from the $RebootTime...??

Comment: I've added and example to ma answer.